# JBoss AS 7 update system property via cli

Tags: configuration, jboss7.x

I can read system properties via the CLI interface by

`/system-property=propertyname:read-attribute(name="value")`

Is there a simple way I can update the property via the CLI interface?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `write-attribute` operation to change system property values.

```
/system-property=propertyname:write-attribute(name="value", value="newValue")
```

See the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134502/152794) for a better description.

Comment: No need for a feature request, as the write-attribute operation can update these attributes as the name suggests.

Comment: Yes, that definitely works. Not sure why it wasn't working when I tried it earlier, but I was probably just using it wrong :-)

Comment: Is it possible to create / overwrite a property? If I add an existent property I get an error and if I write-attribute a non existent property I gent another error.

Comment: Hi, How to change multiple attributes at single query. I have tried update-properties commands but which is not working correctly... Can you give me an IDEA?

Comment: You'd have to use the CLI batch command and then execute-batch. There is no way to update multiple properties in a single command.

Comment: is server restart required for reflecting this new value?

Comment: Depends on how the value is used. If you need it during deployment processing or in say a singleton of some sort, yes.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `write-attribute` operation.

A healthy workflow for the Management CLI is to expose, read and write resource attributes. To give an example of this workflow, we are going to doing the following steps on a fresh default installation of JBoss Application Server 7.1.0Beta1.

### Steps to identify and write a system resource attribute

1. Read all system properties
2. Read a specific system property in more detail
3. Expose an example system property attribute
4. Write an example system property attribute
5. Expose the change to confirm it
6. Reset the attribute back to the original value

### 1. Read all system properties

We don't always know the exact name of what we are looking for. We can use a mix of tab completion and wildcard searches to make it easy to expose the resources and attributes. The `read-resource` operation is a great start to any workflow, as it exposes all present entities.

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] /system-property=*:read-resource
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
        "address" => [("system-property" => "java.net.preferIPv4Stack")],
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "boot-time" => true,
            "value" => "true"
        }
    }]
}
```

### 2. Read a specific system property in more detail

The `read-resource` operation has exposed the `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` property. We can query this further by using the `read-resource-description` operation.

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] /system-property=java.net.preferIPv4Stack:read-resource-description 
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "description" => "A system property to set on all servers in the domain.",
        "head-comment-allowed" => true,
        "tail-comment-allowed" => false,
        "attributes" => {
            "value" => {
                "type" => STRING,
                "description" => "The value of the system property.",
                "required" => false,
                "access-type" => "read-write",
                "storage" => "configuration",
                "restart-required" => "no-services"
            },
            "boot-time" => {
                "type" => BOOLEAN,
                "description" => "If true the system property is passed on the command-line to the started server jvm. If false, it will be pushed to the server as part of the startup sequence.",
                "required" => false,
                "default" => true,
                "access-type" => "read-write",
                "storage" => "configuration",
                "restart-required" => "no-services"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Expose an example system property attribute

The `read-resource-description` operation prints information about the resource, including its attributes. We can specifically query these attributes with the `read-attribute` operation. Again, tab completion makes it easy to compose these operation strings as you begin typing, and hit tab to complete the string or to suggest available additions.

[domain@localhost:9999 /] /system-property=java.net.preferIPv4Stack:read-attribute(name=boot-time)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => true
}

### 4. Write an example system property attribute

In the same way that we just queried the attribute, we can change it. In this case, we can use the `write-attribute` operation, keeping in mind the intended value type as reported by the `read-resource-description` operation. This operation declared the attributed to be BOOLEAN, but you should be able to work this out simply by looking at the existing value in the `read-attribute` command (where it is defined).

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] /system-property=java.net.preferIPv4Stack:write-attribute(name=boot-time, value=false)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "domain-results" => {"step-1" => undefined},
        "server-operations" => undefined
    }
}
```

### 5. Expose the change to confirm it

We can run the `read-attribute` operation again to show the value change.

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] /system-property=java.net.preferIPv4Stack:read-attribute(name=boot-time)              
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => false
}
```

### 6. Reset the attribute back to the original value

Just to gracefully end the example, let's change the value back to the original state.

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /] /system-property=java.net.preferIPv4Stack:write-attribute(name=boot-time, value=true) 
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "domain-results" => {"step-1" => undefined},
        "server-operations" => undefined
    }
}
```

### Summary

Yes, you can write attribute values. To make the process easier, a workflow habit of exposing the attribute values and file type definitions is a good practice, and should make the process clearer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot. Do I need to run another command for the change to take effect? I was able to change the value, but it seems that jboss did not recognize the change.

Answer (score 3):

And for completeness, here's how to remove (undefine) a property attribute:

```
/system-property=propertyname:undefine-attribute(name=attribute-name)
```